# External Tool Development for SQL Server Management Studio 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

Does anyone have any experience of developing external tools for SSMS 2005.

Ideally I would like to be able to interact with the query windows directly, for example, taking the query text from the window to perform some processing on it.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late entry...

[Example of how to do it here](http://jcooney.net/archive/2007/11/26/55358.aspx)

[And here too](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-create-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx)

Comment: A late entry but a good one.  I ended up using both those examples along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Sql Server Management Objects (SMO)?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The best example of this I have seen for SSMS is [SQL Prompt by Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm)

SQL Prompt runs a seperate .NET app that sits in your systray and is in some way part of the magic of the integration.

For loading an add-in, you will want to create a key under:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\AddIns\

...in order to have SSMS load your add-in.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This link explains adding external tools to ssms with screen shots.
It also has procedure to add them as a button.
http://sqlserverlearner.com/2011/sql-server-external-tools